# Create a user with write-only and only in one specific folder

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I created a new user with `adduser jusa`. I started `visudo`. How do I need to change the line

```
jusa  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to make `jusa` only have access to a specific folder `/var/www/vhosts/folder`?

How do I make the folder `/var/www/vhosts/folder` the only one `jusa` can write in?